# Get second largest number from json object in python

Tags: python, json, object

I am trying to get the second largest value from a json file. I have managed to get the largest value but not the second value, how would I do this?

this is what I have so far:

```
    with open('leaderBoard.json') as f:
        events = json.load(f)
        event = max(events['names'], key=lambda ev: ev['points'])
        print(event)
```

output:

```
{'PrevStreak': False, 'Streak': 0, 'name': 'kk#7565', 'points': 2000}
```

and this is my json file:

```
{
    "names": [

        {
            "PrevStreak": false,
            "Streak": 0,
            "name": "kk#7565",
            "points": 2000
        },

        {
            "PrevStreak": false,
            "Streak": 0,
            "name": "ff#7565",
            "points": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

any help is great,
Thanks

Comment: You could sort them, then get the second item: `event = sorted(events['names'], key=lambda ev: ev['points'], reverse = True)[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first sort json and then get the value:

```
with open('leaderBoard.json') as f:
        events = json.load(f)
        events = sorted(events["names"], key=lambda ev: ev["points"])
        event = events[-2]
        print(event)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 0 is the minimal number of points,

```
with open('leaderBoard.json') as f:
    events = json.load(f)
    max_points = max(events['names'], key=lambda ev: ev['points'])
    2nd_points = max(events['names'], key=lambda ev: ev['points'] if ev['points'] < max_points else 0)
    print(2nd_points)
```